# Chat app using ionic,angular and firebase: problem in sending and recieving messages in the chatroom

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework

I am trying to send and recieve message using firebase in the chatroom. but the code is not working and it`s not showing any errors on the web page.I am using firebase. I want the code to automatically create a collection for messages. This code is for chat.page

`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ChatRoom } from '../../models/chat-room';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FirestoreService } from 'src/app/services/firestore.service';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { CreateChatRoomModalComponent } from 'src/app/components/create-chat-room-modal/create-chat-room-modal.component';
import { Message } from 'src/app/models/message';
import { ChatroomComponent } from 'src/app/components/chat-room/chat-room.component';

@Component({
selector: 'app-chats',
templateUrl: './chats.page.html',
styleUrls: \['./chats.page.scss'\]

})
export class ChatsPage implements OnInit {
chatRooms: ChatRoom\[\] = \[\];

currentUserId!: string;
roomName = '';
description = '';
roomId = '';
isModalOpen = false;
hover = true;
private messagesCollection!: AngularFirestoreCollection\<Message\>;
messages: any;
selectedChat: ChatRoom | undefined;
creatorId = '';
receiverId='';

constructor(
private firestoreService: FirestoreService,
private router: Router,
private firestore: AngularFirestore,
private modalController: ModalController
) {}

ngOnInit() {
this.firestoreService.getChatRooms().subscribe(chatRooms =\> {
this.chatRooms = chatRooms;
});

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.currentUserId = user.uid;
      }
    });

}

createChatRoom() {
const chatRoom = new ChatRoom(
this.roomName,
this.description,
Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15),
this.creatorId,
this.receiverId
);

    this.firestoreService
      .createChatRoom(chatRoom)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Chatroom created successfully');
        this.router.navigate(['/chat-room', chatRoom.roomId]);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error creating chatroom:', error);
      });

}

async openChatRoom(chatRoom: ChatRoom) {`your text`
const modal = await this.modalController.create({
component: ChatRoomComponent,
componentProps: {
chatRoom: chatRoom
}
});

    await modal.present();

}

async openModal() {
const modal = await this.modalController.create({
component: CreateChatRoomModalComponent,
componentProps: {
roomName: this.roomName,
description: this.description
}
});

    modal.onDidDismiss().then(data => {
      this.isModalOpen = false;
      if (data.role === 'created') {
        const chatRoom: ChatRoom = data.data;
        this.chatRooms.push(chatRoom);
      }
    });
    
    this.isModalOpen = true;
    return await modal.present();

}

closeModal() {
this.modalController.dismiss();
}
}
```

and chatroom.component.ts code is here

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ChatRoom } from 'src/app/models/chat-room';
import { Message } from 'src/app/models/message';
import { FirestoreService } from 'src/app/services/firestore.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-chatroom',
templateUrl: './chatroom.component.html',
styleUrls: \['./chatroom.component.css'\]
})
export class ChatroomComponent implements OnInit {
chatRoom$!: Observable\<ChatRoom | undefined\>;
roomId!: string;
newMessage: string = '';

constructor(
private db: AngularFirestore,
private route: ActivatedRoute,
private firestoreService: FirestoreService
) {}

ngOnInit() {
this.chatRoom$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
switchMap(params =\> {
this.roomId = params.get('id')!;
return this.firestoreService.getChatRoom(this.roomId);
})
);
}

sendMessage() {
const currentUser = this.firestoreService.currentUserId;
const message: Message = {
text: this.newMessage,
createdAt: new Date(),
senderId: currentUser!,
roomId: this.roomId,
user: {
name: '',
avatarUrl: ''
},
read: false,
id: '',
receiverId: ''
};
this.firestoreService.addMessage(this.roomId, message, currentUser!);
this.newMessage = '';
}
}\`\`
```

Please let me know where is the problem? TIA

I have 2 modals chat-r00ms and messages.ts.

```
\`export class Message {
    id: string;
    text: string;
    createdAt: Date;
    senderId: string;
    receiverId: string;
    roomId: string;
    user!: { name: string; avatarUrl: string; };
    read: boolean;

constructor(text: string, senderId: string, receiverId: string, roomId: string) {
this.text = text;
this.senderId = senderId;
this.receiverId = receiverId;

> this.roomId = roomId;
> this.createdAt = new Date();
> this.id = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15);
> this.read = false;
> this.user = { name: '', avatarUrl: '' };
> }
> }\`
```

`

Comment: Is this \ a typo in your paste or indeed a part of your code: `switchMap(params =\> {`?

Comment: its a typo in the paste.

Comment: its a typo in the paste.